# Accessing Methods from ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I was wondering how to access specific elements of objects in an ArrayList using methods, yet I can't seem to get it to work.
**I have a Phone object that has an int price and String color, as well as a method that returns the color.**

```
public class Phone

{
private int price;
private String color;
```

---

```
public String getColor()
{
return color;
}
```

---

**Now let's say I created an array list of Phone objects called phoneCatalog, and added various Phones.
How can I count how many phones are red?  This is my attempt that isn't working:**

```
int count = 0;

for(int x = 0; x < phoneCatalog.size(); x++)
if((phoneCatalog.get(x)).getColor.equals("red")
count++;
```

Comment: `if((phoneCatalog.get(x)).getColor.equals("red")`
should be
`if(phoneCatalog.get(x).getColor().equals("red")` right?
what do you mean _This is my attempt that isn't working_?
tell us the problem

Answer (score 2):

You need put your `count` inside your if-statment so that every time the conditon becomes true the value of count will get updated .Like below :

```
    public class Main {
    private int price;
    private String color;
    public Main(int price, String color) {
        this.price = price;
        this.color = color;


    }
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        ArrayList < Main > list = new ArrayList < Main > ();
        list.add(new Main(1, "Red")); //Adding object in arraylist    
        list.add(new Main(2, "Blue"));
        list.add(new Main(3, "Red"));
        list.add(new Main(4, "Red"));
        int count = 0;
        //looping through values
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            //checking all value in array list 
            if (list.get(i).getColor().equals("Red")) {
                count++;//increment count
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Red Color are " + count);
    }
}
```

**Output** :

```
Total Red Color are 3
```

Comment: Don't want to be a critic but the whole `psvm` can be replaced with 1 line: `long count = Stream.of(new Main(1, "Red"), new Main(...), ...).map(Main::getColor).filter(c -> c.equals("Red")).count();`

Comment: Didn't know about that .Thanks for your suggestion .